# php script to search multiple webpages from file for specific word

Tags: php

First excuse me for the bad english.

I am trying to build a php script to search multiple webpages from a .txt file for specific word.

More specific:

I have a .txt file where i have stored many urls (every url is on one line, so if i have 10 urls the file have 10 lines) and i want the script to check the webpage content of each url for a specific word. So if the word is found on the webpage the script will return ONLINE othewise will return DOWN.

I build the script but the problem is that it always return ONLINE even if the url from file doesn't have the specific word in it's webpage content.

```
<?php  
$allads = file("phpelist.txt");  
print("Checking urls: <br><br><br><strong>");  
for($index = 0; $index <count($allads); $index++)  
{  
$allads[$index] = ereg_replace("\n", "", $allads[$index]);  
$data = file_get_contents('$allads[$index]');  
$regex = '/save/';  
if (preg_match($regex, $data)) {  
echo "$allads[$index]</strong>...ONLINE<br><strong>";  
} else {  
echo "$allads[$index]</strong>...DOWN<br><strong>";  
}  
}  
print("</strong><br><br><br>I verified all urls from file!");  
?
```

Answer (score 0):

To search the particular webpage for a given string, I'd use [`stripos()`](http://php.net/stripos) (case-insensitive) or [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) (case-sensitive) instead of regular expressions:

```
if( stripos(haystack, needle) !== FALSE ) {
   //the webpage contains the word
}
```

An example:

```
$str = 'sky is blue';
$wordToSearchFor = 'sky';

if (strpos($str, $wordToSearchFor) !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
else {
    echo 'Uh oh.';
}
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/coTiwsj2)

Although, programmitcally skimming through webpages isn't considered a good practice and shouldn't be done unless it's absolutely necessary.

UPDATE:

In your `file_get_contents` call you're doing:

```
$data = file_get_contents('$allads[$index]');
```

You're using single quotes, and the variable values do not get replaced. You'll have to use double quotes to have `file_get_contents` fetch the actual URL. Replace it with:

```
$data = file_get_contents("$allads[$index]");
```

Another thing I noticed is that you're using the deprecated `ereg_replace()` function in your code. [See the red box?](http://php.net/ereg_replace) Relying on depreacted functions are highly discouraged.

Your code, after all the above corrections, should look like:

```
$allads = file("phpelist.txt");  
print("Checking urls: <br><br><br><strong>");  

for($index = 0; $index <count($allads); $index++)  
{  
    $allads[$index] = str_replace("\n", "", $allads[$index]);  
    $data = file_get_contents("$allads[$index]");  

    $searchTerm = 'the';  

    if (stripos($data, $searchTerm) !== false) {
        echo "$allads[$index]</strong>...ONLINE<br><strong>";  
    } 
    else 
    {  
        echo "$allads[$index]</strong>...DOWN<br><strong>";  
    }  
}  

print("</strong><br><br><br>I verified all urls from file!");  
?>
```

Comment: OK if you have the time, can you please give me an example, then i will customize my own script, thanks.

Comment: Ok so in your example the $str is the URL(webpage)?

Comment: I did the changes but it still return TRUE to all urls from my file even if some of them do not contain the specific word.

Comment: @toatatreaba: Can you give me an example of one such URL and word?

Comment: @toatatreaba: It does work. See this **[working demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/CGML9G).**

Comment: Yes i agree, it is working perfect if you use it on a SINGLE url, but when i am using it on the multiple urls i have on the .txt files it just return TRUE to each of the url even if some of the urls doesn't contain the specific word...i don't get what i am doing wrong, maybe you can check the script i posted in my first post and identify the problem, thanks for patience

Comment: For some reason it still doesn't work, it returns ONLINE for each urls on file, i did check manually each of the urls and not all of them contain the word...damn

If i am using the single URL version of the script it works perfect on each of the urls...

Comment: Try to troubleshoot and fix the problem yourself. I'm afraid I can't help you any further, sorry.